# How to move a file from one S3 Client to another S3 client

Tags: java, amazon-s3

If I have two aws service accounts, each with an access to an s3 bucket (neither have access to both). Is there an efficient way to send files between each bucket?

This is what I have so far:

```
System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.DISABLE_CERT_CHECKING_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");

//first account client
AWSCredentials credentialsFrom = new BasicAWSCredentials(fromAccessKey, fromSecretKey);
AmazonS3 s3ClientFrom = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentialsFrom)).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();

//second account client
AWSCredentials credentialsTo = new BasicAWSCredentials(toAccessKey, toSecretKey);
AmazonS3 s3ClientTo = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentialsTo)).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();

//get contents from first s3 client
ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequestFrom = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(fromBucket).withPrefix(fromPrefix).withDelimiter("/");
ObjectListing listingFrom = s3ClientFrom.listObjects(listObjectsRequestFrom);

//get each file from first s3 client
for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary: listingFrom.getObjectSummaries()) {
    S3Object s3Object = s3ClientFrom.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(fromBucket, objectSummary.getKey()));
    //if current key is not a directory
    if(!objectSummary.getKey().substring(objectSummary.getKey().length() - 1).equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
        //get name of the file by splitting the key/path by "/"
        String[] fileName = objectSummary.getKey().split("[/]");

        //put current file contents to new bucket
        s3ClientTo.putObject(toBucket, toPrefix + fileName[fileName.length - 1], s3Object.getObjectContent(), s3Object.getObjectMetadata());
    }
}
```

Comment: looks good so far (no eye-catchers), any problems?

Comment: @xerx593 so when I run the code on debug, everything seems okay. But when I go to the s3 bucket on the AWS console, the file does not appear in the new directory. So the copy isn't actually happening. Not really sure what's going on.

I'm running this as test `movefiles(bucket1, prefix1, key1, secret1, bucket1, prefix2, key1, secret1)` Basically connection to the same account - but trying to copy to a different directory on the same bucket to test

Comment: oh, then `toPrefix + fileName[fileName.length - 1]` is my biggest suspect... and `toPrefix` not detailed in OP.

Comment: @xerx593 Nevermind. It seems like there was a time lag between running my code and the file physically showing up on the AWS console UI (took several minutes, ridiculous). Sorry about that lol. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: cool, that it works! nice "question" (article)!;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the code snippet in the question is the correct way to do it. I'll update the answer if anyone else has a better/cleaner solution. Thank you xerx593 for your help!